# Overriden operator in a struct gets error when used "Cannot be applied..."

Tags: c#, struct

MyDate is a struct that contains year, month, day, Span a constructor and some other methods. I thought I would try to override a few operators and see if I could make that work. I found an example in MSDN of overriding an operator in a struct and tried to duplicate it with the action I needed.
I added this code to the struct MyDate to override "-", subtract.

```
   public static int operator -(MyDate a, MyDate b)
    {
        return a.Span - b.Span;
    }
```

When I use it in another program:

```
        MyDate aDate = new MyDate(2, 15, 1990);
        MyDate bDate = new MyDate(3, 15, 1990);
        lAns = bDate - aDate;
```

I get the error:
Error   1   Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'EulerLibrary.MyDate' and 'EulerLibrary.MyDate'  C:\Users\Henry Wollman\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EulerProblem19\EulerProblem19\Form1.cs 115 20  EulerProblem19

any thoughts on why this does not work? As I said earlier it mirrors the example in MSDN exactly.

Comment: `-` is not overloaded for your **own data type**. You have to overload that operator.

Comment: It should work as described. So your actual code is not what was described. Can you post a self-contained repro?

Comment: This should work ok, are you referencing an old version of the assembly in your other project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `operator -` code you presented in the question is included inside the definition of `MyDate`, then what you have posted should work just fine.

Because you say "When I use it in another program" I assume that what's happened is that the assembly in which `MyDate` is defined is stale (e.g., the other program is picking up a different copy than that in which you added the overloaded operator). Maybe there was a compilation error of the `MyDate` assembly, and it isn't being rebuilt?

Comment: I thought that might be the issue and have recompiled the library that contains the MyDate struct definition. I have had a little trouble with the library. I can't find an easy way to specify a debug or release build, and sometimes the symbols file does not get included but the reference does not seem to give me a way to make sure the symbols get loaded. I have worked out a system of modifying and building the library in one instance of Visual Studio and then my program that uses the library in another instance and it usually works. Other changes I have made have shown up. I will give it look.

Comment: I had to dig a bit but eventually found that the reference was pointed to the wrong dll. Now it compiles and I just have to debug a few things. Thanks for the help.